# Can't get self_collide working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

[arm.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14398153029914819.world)Hi everybody,

I'm building a simple arm robot. I built a world containing the ground, a sun and my arm. Then I simply launch the world using the command "gazebo arm.world" and let my arm robot fall down. But the several links of the robot don't collide. I put the tag "<self_collide>" to "true" in my arm model and I also tried to use a model_plugin to programmatically set the "self_collide" attribute for each link to "true".

Does anyone have an idea why there is no collision ? (I looked with the view->collision but nothing happens).  Could it be because my links don't have any inertial properties ?

I just need the two fingers of the arm to collide together but have no idea how to process...

Cheers,

Debz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9128/can%27t-get-self_collide-working/) by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 198 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-08-12**:
You say nothing happens when you do view->collisions - are you sure your model has collisions? You should see orange transparent representations of them. Maybe try making the model itself transparent so its easier to see collisions.

**Comment by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on 2015-08-14**:
Yes I did exactly what you said (view -> transparent and collisions). But nothing seems to happen. I actually would like the two fingers to be not able to get through each other (like in a real world). I know that two links connected by a joint will never collide, but here it is not the case...

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2015-08-14**:
So it seems like you haven't added collisions to your model's SDF. Try adding some [collision](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision) elements?

**Comment by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) on 2015-08-17**:
Yes I did ! I added the code of the world I did in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok, I solved this.
The tag <self_collide>1</self_collide> had to be added in the two links of the two fingers.
I read in the documentation that it was possible to declare it for the entire model, but it is not !

---

Originally posted by [debz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1306/debz/) with karma: 198 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0